# Identity element for std::min/float monoid

Tags: c++, monoids

In [this](https://youtu.be/giWCdQ7fnQU?t=623) (very interesting) talk the speaker poses a question:

> What is the e value for the float/std::min monoid.

In other words: what is the identity element for the monoid composed of standard C++ floats and std::min operation? The speaker says that the answer is "interesting".

I think that `std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()` should be the answer, as evidenced by the code:

```
  const auto max = numeric_limits<float>::max();
  const auto min = numeric_limits<float>::min();
  const auto nan = numeric_limits<float>::signaling_NaN();
  const auto nan2 = numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
  const auto inf = numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
  const auto minus_inf = -inf;
  cout << std::min(max, inf) << "\n";
  cout << std::min(min, inf) << "\n";
  cout << std::min(nan, inf) << "\n";
  cout << std::min(nan2, inf) << "\n";
  cout << std::min(inf, inf) << "\n";
  cout << std::min(minus_inf, inf) << "\n";
```

Which prints:

```
3.40282e+38
1.17549e-38
nan
nan
inf
-inf
```

We always get the left argument when calling std::min in the tests. Is infinity the correct answer or am I missing something?

EDIT: I seemed to have missed something. This:

```
  cout << std::min(nan, inf) << "\n";
  cout << std::min(inf, nan) << "\n";
```

prints:

```
nan
inf
```

So we get different answers based on the order of arguments in case of NaN shenanigans.

Comment: Couldn't "NaN shenanigans" be just "sheNaNigans"?

Comment: Note that your signaling NaN gets normalized to a quiet NaN on actual calculations if you don't enable exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obviously true that `min` on the affinely-extended reals (ie, including +/-inf but excluding NaN) is a monoid.

However, the result of comparing anything to `NaN` is *not* false, but "[unordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Comparison_predicates)". This implies that `<` is only a partial order on `float`, and `std::min<float>` (which is defined in terms of `<`) is therefore not a monoid.

There is in IEEE 754 a `totalOrder` predicate - although I don't know how it is exposed in C++, if at all. We could write our own `min` in terms of this instead of `<`, and that *would* form a monoid ... but it wouldn't be `std::min`.

---

For confirmation, we can compile a variant of your code on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dn1r9c), to see how this is implemented in practice:

- the comparison is done with [`comiss`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/comiss), which has the possible results

  ```
    UNORDERED: ZF,PF,CF←111;
    GREATER_THAN: ZF,PF,CF←000;
    LESS_THAN: ZF,PF,CF←001;
    EQUAL: ZF,PF,CF←100;
  ```

  and specifies that

  > The unordered result is returned if either source operand is a NaN (QNaN or SNaN).
- the branch is done with [`jbe`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc), which will

  > Jump short if below or equal (CF=1 or ZF=1).

You can see that the UNORDERED result is actually treated as both less than *and* equal by this conditional branch.

So, assuming this is a legal model of the unordered comparison mentioned by IEEE 754, it should be permissible to have both

```
min(min(+inf, NaN), -inf) =
min(+inf, -inf)           = -inf
```

and

```
min(+inf, min(NaN, -inf)) =
min(+inf, NaN)            = +inf
```

which means `min<float>` is not associative and is therefore not a monoid.

Comment: But this is not by language definition, right? The standard says "The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined." So this is only true for when e.g. IEEE754 is used. If there's no NaN, it is different?

Comment: Yep, this is only addressing the case where `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559 == true` or otherwise `has_infinity == has_quiet_NaN == true`

Comment: ... although arguably since that's a _legal_ implementation, it's sufficient to demonstrate you can't rely on `min<float>` forming a monoid in general. It doesn't prevent it forming a monoid on some particular implementation (presumably without a quiet NaN).